# How to open `set image as` intent in react native?

Tags: react-native, android-intent, wallpaper

I am beginner developer of react native. I am making demo of wallpaper application in which I need to open image in slider and then when click on any perticular image.

At that time I need to ope `set Image as bottomsheet` for choose option like **Lockscreen** Or **Home screen**.

I Already tried NPM package for it. but it is not working in my application. some version mismatch issue (app is crashing if that NPM I install.)

After spending lot's of time I found that in Android Same function is called `set Image as` intent. But I don't know how to use it in `React Native`

Can Anyone Help Me Please ?

Answer (score 0):

A quick way to search for images from the gallery is using the package react-native-image-crop-picker https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker.

Comment: I need a `set image as` intent code that is enable to open BottomSheet with options. Not Cropper.

Comment: Similar to this example: https://github.com/InterfaceKit/react-native-js-bottom-sheet ?

Comment: Yes, Exact Similar to this but in that example component i.e. display inside bottomsheet is made by developer. But I need default option of device that enable to set wallpaper on screen.